# Reverse DNS for nameservers

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

Do I need PTR records for nameserver (bind dns servers)?

I understand that it's important for sending mail to have a reverse dns record in place, but as our nameservers would not send mail, is this required?

One of the servers are setup through Google Cloud, and from my understanding they do not allow PTR records to be setup for a static ip address.

When doing a check on mxtoolbox.com, I am only warned of SOA TTL which are too high and that "Could not find reverse address for ...". It however is only flagged for one of the 4 nameservers (the other 3 appears to be correct).

Comment: I'm not really familiar with GCE myself (I assume that is what you are using?) but from I just read it appears that there actually are reverse DNS entries, you just can't customize them.  This is not what you asked but it may make your question largely irrelevant to your situation.

Answer (score 3):

No, the standards for DNS do not require that nameservers have valid PTR records for their IP addresses.

Comment: Arguably any address in use should have a valid `PTR` record set up but I agree that there's nothing it about being used for a nameserver specifically that makes this more important than for other hosts.

Comment: @Håkan Arguably, yeah. NXDOMAIN for a PTR record is better than a NOERROR that is wrong, and mandatory reverse DNS policies inevitably lead to the latter since most shops do not have reliable cleanup policies. Since the intent of our comments is to keep people well informed, I'm going to steer this conversation in the direction of [this Q&A](http://serverfault.com/questions/612833/do-internet-standards-require-reverse-dns-for-every-device/).