# Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner - G Suite

Tags: mx-record, g-suite

I ran our domain through MXToolbox, and this error comes up several times:
"Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner".

We use G Suite for our email and Cloudflare for DNS. Can I fix these warnings from MXtoolbox? Since I obviously don't run the SMTP server (Google does), I'm thinking these aren't fixable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

They're saying that your forward lookups (A) don't match your reverse lookups(PTR). Talk to your ISP, they can edit them or give you the tools to do it.

Comment: The addresses in question belong to Google.

Answer (score 0):

Those are warnings not errors right?

It would implicate to many drawbacks on a working protocol to have this required.

Discussion here too: 
[Do internet standards require reverse DNS for every device?](https://serverfault.com/questions/612833/do-internet-standards-require-reverse-dns-for-every-device)

Answer (score 0):

This warning is not a serious problem, and in most cases, it will not prevent your emails from being delivered. However, some mail servers may use this as an indication of a possible spam source in a scoring system. This means that your emails may be more likely to be marked as spam or even rejected outright.

to fix this you have to contact the Workspace / Google support to have them update the PTR record.